# Process function to NAND and use only negative conjunction functions

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I have a system built only NAND implementing this function.

[image]

I have to process this function using only De Morgan's law and finally get only negation conjuction functions.

I did it but I'm not sure is it good. Could you help me?

[image]

++++ UPDATE:
I did this gate also in CEDAR, is it correct?
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$Y = (X_1 \cdot X_2) + \overline {(X_3 \cdot \overline {X_1}) + X_2} $$

Double negation: \$ X =  \overline{\overline{X}}\$

$$Y = \overline {\overline {(X_1 \cdot X_2) + \overline {(X_3 \cdot \overline {X_1}) + X_2}}} $$

Take deMorgan's:

$$Y = \overline {\overline {(X_1 \cdot X_2)} \cdot \overline {\overline {(X_3 \cdot \overline {X_1}) + X_2}}} $$

Take deMorgan's on 2nd term:

$$Y = \overline {\overline {(X_1 \cdot X_2)} \cdot \overline {\overline {(X_3 \cdot \overline {X_1})} \cdot \overline {X_2}}} $$

Comment: Thank you for help. Now I know where I did a mistake.